# Считывание данных из устройства чтения смарт карт

Tags: nfc

как то я уже задавал вопрос о том как заполнять инпут из устройства баркод сканера, тогда мне решили этот вопрос за что я благодарю участников стековерфлоу ещё раз. Но вот ещё один вопрос из цикла "сверхизвращение" , прошу сильно не ругать. У меня есть "считыватель" он же Устройство чтения смарт карт а именно ACR1252 1S CL Reader PICC и собственно вопрос как заполнять HTML инпут с помощью этого агрегата ). Он тоже работает как устройство ввода как и баркод сканер или с ним дела обстоят по другому ?

Comment: Через запрос сертификата, если в смарт карте есть сертификат. Если там только ключ или чтото ещё, то пиши локальное приложение и подключаться к нему аяксом)